# option to turn my bash script into a daemon

Tags: linux, bash, shell, daemon

I have a well working bash script to create some random files. It runs a loop which create random bin files and then recreate them after a sleep time.
I would like to give an option so that I can run the script like a daemon. So the script would go in the background, detach stdin, stdout and stderr, maybe even attach itself to init instead of the current bash.
How should I do that?

The script is on github:

https://github.com/momeunier/randombin/blob/master/randombin.sh

Comment: And if possible I would like to keep that in one file. I understand I can call start-stop-daemon to start another process, but I would rather keep everything in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run a subshell:

```
function do_something {
    <stuffs>
}

( do_something; ) &>/dev/null &
disown
```

Comment: i'll try that. sounds promising

Comment: It's looking good except for one thing. My do_something function has an infinite while loop in it and I think it's looping only once. Not sure why.

Comment: Try to redirect output to a file first instead if you want to debug how the daemon works inside. It could be a stdin problem or something if not natural script error: `( do_something; ) &>/some/file &`

Comment: Also remember you can debug your script with `bash -x`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about:

```
./randombin.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

First redirects stdout and stderr to /dev/null and launches the script in the background.

Next command sets init as parent so you can close your terminal without the process exiting.

Comment: I would better have it as an option in the script. Like ./randombin.sh --daemon

Comment: Just let it fork itself into a subshell then :)